Is there anyway where we can skip adding the outbound IPs of consumption logic apps to keyvault firewall to get secret from keyvault?
For the logic apps to get a secret from keyvault, we need to whitelist logic apps outbound IPs in keyvault firewall, and apparently they are not static, and there will be updates to the IPs which needs to be tracked and updated manually, which might be an issue if the update is not noticed which causes the logic apps to fail.  So tried to go with the approach of service tag, apparently we can only add an IP address in the exceptions and not a service tag. Is there any way we can overcome this issue?
Note: Issue is with consumption logic apps, already tried creating an inbound rule in NSG with service tag LogicApps as source and destination as AzureKeyVault Service tag.
Tried with connectors got an issue 

You can use service tag AzureConnectors as the source and AzureKeyVault as the destination; the connection will allow traffic from the Logic App to Key Vault if both are in the same network. If you are accessing Keyvault from connectors, there is no need to add the firewall rules in Keyvault again to allow the connection.

But consumption logic apps cannot be integrated into vnet right? Also by connectors do you mean API Connections?  @VenkatV
I tried that

Yes, consumption Logic Apps don't support VNet. If you create a Logic App with a consumption plan, by default, the connection will go via public, and there is no way to make it private

So is there no way, other than updating the outbound IPs whenever there is change? Cause I tried with connectors, I updated the question with the screenshot of the trial with connectors @VenkatV

You can add a list of outbound IP addresses for Logic Apps in a specific region. By adding all the app's IPs in Key Vault, the connection will only go through those IPs, so it won't cause any issues even after the IP addresses change, Logic Outbound IP's: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519

You can add the Logic App's outbound public IPs for a specific region in the Key Vault firewall section. By adding them this way, the connection won't be affected even if the IPs change, like here

I hope this helps to resolve your issue?

Thank you @VenkatV ! But we were already following that, we added all the outbound IPs of Logic apps to keyvault firewall, but they're not static and hence the issue.

You can add a region-Logic app outbound IP address instead of adding logic app outbound IP's. Those are static; it won't change.

Thank you, will try that and let you know!

Can i post the answer with same point?

Please do, thank you again!


Is there anyway where we can skip adding the outbound IPs of consumption logic apps to keyvault firewall to get secret from keyvault?

The consumption plan doesn't support VNET integration. If you are using the consumption plan, all Logic App outbound traffic will go through specific IP addresses, and these addresses will change randomly, causing the connection to be interrupted.
To resolve the issue, you can add logic app region all outbound IP addresses; this way, even if the logic app IP address changes, the connection will go via different IP's.You no longer need to add the IP's in the Keyvault firewall section when the IP address changes.
Add all the IPs mentioned in the North Central US region. The Logic App's outbound IP traffic will go through only the specified IPs.

You can download the Logic App region outbound IP addresses from here. After downloading the IPs, check the region of your Logic App and add the IPs to the Key Vault firewall section
Reference: Consumption (multitenant)
